How can I remove white space created by dropMenu
I have some actionButtons which are nicely arranged but when I add a dropMenu, I get a bunch of white space which I dont understand why. How can I remove this?
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(tidyverse)


style <- "font-size:80%; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:left"

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  card(
    card_header(
      "Plot",
    ),
    plotOutput("plot"),
    card_footer(
      card_body(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".no_gap { gap: 0rem; }"))),
        layout_column_wrap(width = 1/5, class = "no_gap",
          dropMenu(actionButton("labels", "Labels", icon = icon("tag"), style = style), padding =  "0px"),
          dropMenu(actionButton("axes", "Axes", icon = icon("lines-leaning"), style = style), padding = "0px"),
          dropMenu(actionButton("theme", "Theme", icon = icon("palette"), style = style), padding = "0px"),
          dropMenu(actionButton("options", "Options", icon = icon("sliders"), style = style), padding = "0px"),
          dropMenu(actionButton("sort", "Select & Sort", icon = icon("sort"), style = style), padding = "0px")
        ))),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
      geom_point()
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


How it should look


What do you mean by 'a bunch of white table'? Can you include a picture of your ideal state? (It can be hand drawn.) When I run your app, I get a line of buttons along the bottom of a graph.

@Kat, sorry there was a typo. I updated the question with pictures.

I'm going to give you a simplified version of the styling. You've got several styles called, but I'm not sure if that's because that is what you wanted or if you were just trying to get anything to respond (??) I didn't include them here, but, you can, or course, add your styles back.
The only change is to the content in tags$head. Although, because I dropped your styles, I've included the entire UI, as I used it.
There are two styles set in the updated tags$head:

div:has(button) (this is the button parent)
button

When you add dropMenu it adds a div tag between button and it's parent. The width and height were inherited from a flex style parent, when the div was added, it didn't inherit this style and therefore didn't pass it to the child element - the button.
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  card(
    card_header(
      "Plot",
    ),
    plotOutput("plot"),
    card_footer(
      card_body(
                                    # button parent and button - these styles are new
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div:has(button) {display: flex; flex-grow: 1;}   
                                  button {width: 100%}"))),
        layout_column_wrap(width = 1/5, class = "no_gap",
                           dropMenu(actionButton("labels", "Labels", icon = icon("tag"))),  # previous styles removed
                           dropMenu(actionButton("axes", "Axes", icon = icon("lines-leaning"))),
                           dropMenu(actionButton("theme", "Theme", icon = icon("palette"))),
                           dropMenu(actionButton("options", "Options", icon = icon("sliders"))),
                           dropMenu(actionButton("sort", "Select & Sort", icon = icon("sort")))
        ))),
  )
)

With no other styles, this is what you get:

